# How are the Battle Points you earn calculated?

Tags: dota-2

What in game events affect how many points I earn? Is there a cap to how many I can earn in one match? Do I get points regardless of winning or losing?

Comment: you get points regardless of winning or losing. i don't know about the rest

Comment: I'm mostly interested in how some players generate the +15% battle point boosts.

Answer (score 31):

Generally speaking you get a number of battle points proportional to how much time the match last but I don't know if this number is capped in some way.

You won’t earn rewards or Battle Points instead if:

- You are in the low priority pool.
- You abandon a game / trigger a leaver penalty.
- You are in a practice lobby.

#### Update - Some measurements

I am trying to log all matches I do writing down time, battle points earned and some notes. Here it is my current log:

```
BP +58 after 39:59 W 11/2/23
BP +66 after 50:48 W 6/11/15
BP +59 after 45:33 L 3/9/11
BP +39 after 30:31 L 4/6/5 with a leaver
BP +45 after 34:16 W 5/6/19
BP +44 after 30:12 L 1/5/7 with 2 leavers
BP +62 after 47:27 L 3/15/15 
BP +64 after 47:48 L 1/15/7
BP +38 after 23:32 L 1/10/7     
BP +71 after 54:17 L 3/8/18
BP +60 after 40:40 L 6/11/10
BP +74 after 56:26 L 5/13/10
BP +37 after 28:31 W 9/2/9 with leavers
BP +42 after 32:07 W 10/1/11
BP +33 after 18:30 W 4/4/8 with leavers
BP +41 after 31:00 W 7/7/15
BP +38 after 29:20 L 4/10/11 with leavers
BP +54 after 37:32 L 4/10/3
BP +66 after 50:14 L 8/10/18
```

[image: chart battle points per second]

### TL;DR

The output of these data is that you gain about **~0.023 battle points per seconds (1,4/minute - 83/hour)** and I didn't found any relations between battle points earned, win/loss or the presence of leavers inside one or the other team.

*I will continue log data and update this answer time to time.*

Comment: This is a pretty good start to figuring out the formula. It is definitely not easy to figure out the exact calculations due to the large number of factors that may come into play per game, although more data will probably refine your results.

Comment: Do you think you could post your statistics as a scatter plot and maybe the MatchID's or scorescreens of some of the bigger outliers? I think that would be a good way to isolate the causes of the variation.

Comment: It would also be potentially interesting to log these same statistics for **all** players in a match.

Comment: I assume that the *balance* of the game is also a factor, by which I mean the Dota 2 levels of all the players in the game.

Comment: @Drake any thought on updating this again sometime?

Comment: So... 19 games means 190 people, -19 for the "you" player makes 171 players total, out of which 6 were leavers. That means 6 out of 171 people you play with will leave according to these statistics, which is 6/171 = 0.035... 3.5% of all the people you play with will be leavers. Why am I counting this?!

Comment: I think (though i'm not sure) that getting all 3 rax would boost BP,maybe you can log that too see if it matters

Answer (score 5):

I have heard that also getting certain points of each match completed can effect the points too.

Rosh
Mega Creeps
ect.

Be sure to keep that in mind if you get 2 almost identical games and find there is a larger gap between your BP's than you calculated.

Answer (score 4):

Battle points within DOTA2 is essentially an experience system.

Battle points can be earned through Matchmaking and Co-op matches. Each time you complete a matchmaking game, you will be rewarded with Battle Points.

Upon obtaining 1000 Battle points, the experience counter resets - with any excess Battle points carrying over to the new counter - and a level is added to the player's profile. As part of levelling up you will also receive a random item.

As per [this article](http://www.dota2.com/news/community/8142/) from the DOTA2 community news site there are limitations to how you can earn Battle points, but there is no cap to the total quantity of Battle points you can collect:

> You won’t earn rewards or Battle Points if:
>
> - You are in the low priority pool.
> - You abandon a game / trigger a leaver penalty.
> - You are in a practice lobby.
>
> There is no cap on the amount of Battle Points you can earn.

Answer (score -1):

It's 15 points + 1 per minute.

Answer (score -1):

guys  the BP system is completly easy.. in a match where u win like all enemies leave untill match starts, u get 15bp  and after every minute u get 1.4bp/min.  no other factors affect the bp rate     except for low priority and abandons