# How are Battle Points calculated in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How are the Battle Points you earn calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71571/how-are-the-battle-points-you-earn-calculated)

I know this is obviously similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71571/how-are-the-battle-points-you-earn-calculated) but i was wondering if there was any new information on it.  I thought since they've been doing lots of updates/it's a growing game, I thought maybe there could be some new info on it.

Before you downvote/close I just wanted to point out that the other question's top answer does not have a legitimate answer, seeing as their graph doesn't have a correlation between time and battle points.

Only thing I've found about them seems to be this:

> Q: What are Battle Levels? What are Battle Points?
>
> A: Each time you complete a matchmaking game, you will be rewarded with Battle Points. Earn enough of them, and your profile's Battle Level will increase, at which point you'll receive a new item.

from [here](http://www.dota2.com/spoilsofwar/faq)

Comment: While the other question doesn't have an answer that completely answers the question, this question *is* a duplicate of the other question and the other question does not have an accepted answer on it yet. Rather than open a duplicate question asking the same thing, it would have been more appropriate to put a bounty on the other question to attract a more complete answer.

Comment: oooooo i like bounties! but i just thought it was pretty old and the current answers just clogged things up

Comment: Yeah but adding a bounty makes a question feature in the 'featured' section of the site, of which there are only currently two other questions - this means that putting a bounty on a question pretty much guarentees it will always be on the first page of 'featured', which is highlighted by a big red block with a number in it

Comment: alright, will do! thanks chief! whoa you did a bounty! thanks a lot